# Can ext-json be disabled?

Tags: php, php-extension

Can the `json` extension be disabled in PHP? The [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php) says that:

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default.

But some people in the comments say that the json extension is sometimes provided as a separate package.

**Can the `json` extension be explicitly disabled, or can we be confident that it's always available?**

---

*Background: I want to make a class in a library of mine implement `JsonSerializable`, but that may be a BC break if the interface is not always declared, and the library suddenly relies on an extension that's not always available.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP 8:

No, the JSON extension [cannot be disabled anymore](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.0beta2/UPGRADING).

### PHP 7:

Yes, any PHP extension can be installed, uninstalled, enabled, or disabled at will.

The `json` extension - despite its ubiquity - is still just an extension and can be removed in this way as well.

There are a couple of cases in which the `json` extension might not exist:

1. The administrator disabled/uninstalled it:

   ```
    ;extension=json
   ```
2. The version of PHP that was installed was compiled from source manually, and the `json` extension was left out:

   ```
    --disable-json
   ```
3. The extension is bundled as a separate package; for example, on Fedora you have to install the `php-json` package explicitly.

The important part of your question: **Can we be confident that it's always available**

Normally, I would say no. However unlikely the case is that this particular extension is disabled or left out, it still doesn't mean that it won't happen.

If your intended audience is limited to people who probably wouldn't touch those kinds of settings, then you *might* be safe, but there's no guarantee.

My suggestion: Build your library as a [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) package, and declare `ext-json` as a dependency. That way, you can provide installation instructions as a Composer package and if the underlying system doesn't meet your package requirements, the installation will fail and the user will be alerted to the missing extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My [library](https://github.com/brick/money) is already published as a Composer package, but implementing `JsonSerializable` therefore adds a dependency, that means a BC break and a version bump then!

Comment: For completeness sake, it would be nice if you could include in your answer the configuration option to disable the json extension.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you already using `json_encode` or `json_decode`? If so, then you already have the dependency on the json extension. You can see everything that the extension adds [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

Comment: No I'm not using it in this particular library, hence my question :)

Comment: Then yes, adding the usage of the extension adds the dependency. A major version bump would be suggested.

Comment: Found the `configure` option. I added it to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I just found out that the `json` extension is not even installed by default on Fedora; I further updated your answer to reflect this, hope you don't mind!

Comment: In PHP 8 the JSON extension cannot no longer be disabled, and is enabled similarly to the Date extension. See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-8.0.0beta2/UPGRADING (grep for JSON to find it).

Comment: @ojrask Thanks, I updated maiorano84's answer accordingly ;-)